# Match Hard Disk Partition Table?

Tags: windows, linux, mbr

What is the most efficient way to match the partition tables on two different hard disks?

I have saved the partition tables using dd command in linux.

The partition tables are from a Windows system.

Answer (score 2):

If you have any extended/logical partitions, using `dd` to copy the MBR will not be sufficient because the detailed information about the logical partions is stored at the front of each logical partition and not at the beginning of the disk.

The most common and simplest way to copy a partition table from one disk to another is to use `sfdisk` like the following:

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sfdisk /dev/sdb
```